# Diebold-Mariano test for predictive accuracy with R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, diebold-mariano-test

The following example code is from the documentation of the command `dm.test` from R.

```
f1 <- ets(WWWusage[1:80])
f2 <- auto.arima(WWWusage[1:80])
f1.out <- ets(WWWusage[81:100],model=f1)
f2.out <- Arima(WWWusage[81:100],model=f2)
accuracy(f1.out)
accuracy(f2.out)
dm.test(residuals(f1.out),residuals(f2.out),h=1)
```

I do not understand why in the last line the forecast horizon is set equal to `h=1`. Since we are predicting the indices `[81:100]` in `f1.out` and `f2.out` I would think we need forecast horizons of `h=1, ..., 20`. I know that `dm.test` cannot be applied in such a situation. But why does it make sense to use `dm.test` with `h=1`? Predicting the values with indices `[81:100]` seems like doing a `h`-step ahead forecast for `h=1, ..., 20`. Why can this be interpreted as a 1-step ahead forecast?

Comment: I haven't read the help on dm.test but my guess is that $h = 1$ is just specifying what horizon to use when comparing. So, $h=1$ is comparing the one step  ahead forecasts for 81:100. This means that, when sitting $T = 80$, the 81st value is forecasted, then , when sitting at $T=81$, the 82nd value is forecasted etc. This is of course a guess but it's probably explained in ?dm.test.

Comment: But I do not know the value at 81 (it is only a forecast). When I compute the value at 82, in fact I do a 2-step-ahead forecast (I only know the true value at 80). So for 83 I need a 3-step forecast and so on. But dm.test treats all the errors as if they come from 1-step ahead forecasts, which is not the case.

Comment: But if you have, say, fitted an AR(1) model $y_t=0.8y_{t-1}$, based on the 80 training observations, you can use that relationship to also construct a forecast for, say, obs. 82 using the relationship and the observed value for period 81.

Comment: But the observations 81 and 82 are both out of sample. I cannot observe them. I can only estimate them using 1-step and 2-step ahead forecasts, repectively.

Comment: My best guess is that they assume you are moving along so that, for the 82nd observation, you are at the time $t=81$, So, you know the values at $t=81$ so, in this manner, 82 is a one step ahead forecast. This is the same as Christoph's last comment.